# Phone form input with Bootstrap inline

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a Bootstrap grid-within-a-grid for a phone input. The idea is that the phone number has a label, and it's acceptable that on smaller resolutions the "label" and "phone group" will stack. HOWEVER, I don't want the 3 phone inputs to stack - I want to keep them inline, but I'm not sure how to use the inline classes in this scenario.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="form-row">
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <label for="ph1">Label</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="label">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">

    <div class="form-inline">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="ph1">Country</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ph1">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="ph2">Area</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ph2">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="ph3">Number</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ph3">
      </div>
    </div>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `form-inline`, nest another `form-row` and use `no-gutters` to limit the space between the inputs. Using `col-*` instead of `col-md-*` will prevent the phone inputs from stacking.

https://www.codeply.com/go/mSrkHKgvgs

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <label for="ph1">Label</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="label">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="form-row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-3">
                <label for="ph1">Country</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ph1">
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                <label for="ph2">Area</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ph2">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <label for="ph3">Number</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ph3">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought I'd tried this, but I couldn't get it working as you have. Works perfectly.